# Install Kernel that's not available from Ubuntu Distro Repository

Tags: linux, drivers, ubuntu-9.10, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 rightnow, but I'd like to install kernel 2.6.33 into it.
I see that there's deb files on kernel sites. Problems is that I cannot just download these deb files and have dpkg install them for me because wireless and graphic drivers cannot be compiled against the new kernel.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If some of your drivers do not work there is no magic way to make them work suddenly. You either have to wait until they are patched to work with the new kernel or live without them. The problem is probably really on the kernel code-level, function signatures may have changed or API's might even have been depreciated altogether.

For some hardware there are other drivers available (i.e. not from the manufacturer but e.g. open source) and they might work earlier or later. It really depends on what you have to work with.